# Why is that the --cached flag seems to refer to different memory in different git commands?

Tags: git

Why does `git rm --cached` remove files from the "index" or "stage", but `git ls-files --cached` list files not from "index" but from the current commit.

I have to use `git ls-files --staged` to list the files in the "index".

I thought the cache, stage, and index were the same thing. Why is that the --cached flag seems to refer to different memory in different commands.

Comment: Though the authors of git are geniuses the virtue of creating *consistent* user interface is not their strong point. See [this git koan](https://stevelosh.com/blog/2013/04/git-koans/#s4-the-hobgoblin) :-)

Comment: @matt just trying to figure out the logic behind designing the cli this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this isn't really a *programming* issue, it is one of the classic Git gotchas.

Some Git commands take `--index` flags (`git apply` in particular).  Some accept `--cached` and `--staged` as synonyms (`git diff` in particular).  Some use `--cached` only (`git rm`) and some use `--staged` only (`git ls-files`).  Why?  (Note: answers to this sort of question usually involve history and/or philosophy.)

As [phd noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355163/why-is-that-the-cached-flag-seems-to-refer-to-different-memory-in-different-gi#comment108541456_61355163), "creating *consistent* user interface is not [a Git] strong point".

There is a Git entity, normally stored in a file—`.git/index` is the most common one—that Git variously calls the *index*, the *staging area*, or (sometimes and now pretty rarely) the *cache*.  There is a separate entity that exists only at run-time inside Git programs that is also called the *cache*.  The confusion of the two names is why "the cache" is now mostly reserved for the in-memory data structure.  So we should call the other one—the on-disk stuff, that's found in `.git/index` or perhaps elsewhere, the *index*, to refer to what it is named and where it resides, or the *staging area* to refer to its main function.

Its main function is that it acts as the *proposed next commit*.  A Git commit always has a snapshot of some set of files, plus whatever metadata is appropriate.

If *you* make a new commit, the new commit has your name and email address as the author and committer, "now" (as determined by your computer's clock) as the date-and-time stamps, and whatever log message you supply as the log message.  The new commit's parent(s) are set automatically by Git as appropriate.  Some additional information, such as the commit text encoding, sign-off lines, GPG signatures, and so on might also be in the metadata.  So this is where the metadata comes from: mostly from you, with a bit supplied by Git itself.  But what about the *snapshot?*

Git makes the snapshot by turning a set of files—file names, modes, and content—that are stored in the index, into a frozen set of files stored in a commit.  (Technically, each files' *content* itself is already in the repository, in the form of a Git *blob object*, but we only see this when we delve into the details of individual index entries.)

We check out some initial commit, making it the current commit, in order to work on it: `git checkout master` or `git switch master`, for instace.  Git copies the selected commit's files into the index, so that the staging area—the index as viewed as the proposed *next* commit—matches the *current* commit.  Git copies the index's files to our work-tree, so that we can touch and smell the files, or whatever it is we do with files stored in their normal form—the files inside a commit are in a special, read-only, Git-only form that the rest of the system can't use at all.

Then, we [fold, spindle, and mutilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Not_Fold,_Spindle_or_Mutilate) the work-tree files to our heart's content.  When we're done with this and wish to make a *new* commit, we must replace the index copies of files.  Using `git add` is the easy way: Git will copy the work-tree version of the file back into the index, replacing the ready-to-commit Git-ized frozen-format version.  Any files we *do not* replace here remain in the same form they have had since we extracted them earlier.  So this arranges the index—*stages* it, in other words—to be ready for the next commit.

So that's where the *names* came from.  But why are the flags inconsistent?  The only real answer here is history.  The term *stage* came about later.  The name *index* was in use from the start.  It's obviously not such a great term: it's too generic.

> On being indexed: [I will not be pushed, filed, stamped, indexed, briefed, debriefed, or numbered.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061287/characters/nm0001526)
> [More on The Prisoner](https://cultbox.co.uk/features/rewind/rewind-the-prisoner-revisited)

The fact that the index *acts as* a staging area probably led to the term *staging area* and the `--staged` flags—although in fact, the way merge works clearly predated this.  During a conflicted merge, the index expands from having *one* copy of each file, to having (up to) *three*.  The three copies are from three different commits, and they get numbered.  These numbers are *staging slot numbers*.  Staging slot #1 is for the merge base, slot #2 is for the "ours" file, and slot #3 is for the "theirs" file.

You resolve a merge conflict by erasing the nonzero staging-slot-number entries from the index and storing a staging-slot-zero entry for the file instead (or removing everything entirely, if the file is supposed to not-exist in the new commit).  Again, `git add` does all this work for you, the easy way: there is no need to fiddle with `git update-index` these days.

There are occasional attempts, as in `git apply`, to distinguish clearly between "just what's in the index" and "what's in the index *and* the work-tree".  For instance, according to [the `git apply` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply):

> `--index`
>
> When `--check` is in effect, or when applying the patch (which is the default when none of the options that disables it is in effect), make sure the patch is applicable to what the current index file records. If the file to be patched in the working tree is not up to date, it is flagged as an error. This flag also causes the index file to be updated.
>
> `--cached`
>
> Apply a patch without touching the working tree. Instead take the cached data, apply the patch, and store the result in the index without using the working tree. This implies `--index`.

That is, `--index` means *touch (modify by patching) both the index and the work-tree* and `--cached` means *touch only the index*.  But `git ls-files` and `git diff` do not *modify* anything, so they don't need this kind of distinction.

Really, I think both terms are not that great, but they have been defined this way for over a decade.  We are pretty much stuck with them.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the description of `--cached`/`--index` options in "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1393f56f4a467b5687106bbb750544437359de52/Documentation/git-apply.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> --help" has been updated.

See [commit d064702](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d064702be39d974d0eee403f4fbae92f8f0534a7) (20 Aug 2020) by [Raymond E. Pasco (`juped`)](https://github.com/juped).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1393f56](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1393f56f4a467b5687106bbb750544437359de52), 31 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-apply.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d064702be39d974d0eee403f4fbae92f8f0534a7): update descriptions of --cached, --index
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Raymond E. Pasco</sup>

> The blurb for "`--cached`" says it implies "`--index`", but in reality "`--cached`" and "`--index`" are distinct modes with different behavior.
>
> Additionally, the descriptions of "`--index`" and "`--cached`" are somewhat unclear about what might be modified, and what "`--index`" looks for to determine that the index and working copy "match".
>
> Rewrite the blurbs for both options for clarity and accuracy.

`git apply` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d064702be39d974d0eee403f4fbae92f8f0534a7/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L64-L70):

> ### `--index`:
>
> Apply the patch to both the index and the working tree (or
> merely check that it would apply cleanly to both if `--check` is
> in effect).
>
> Note that `--index` expects index entries and
> working tree copies for relevant paths to be identical (their
> contents and metadata such as file mode must match), and will
> raise an error if they are not, even if the patch would apply
> cleanly to both the index and the working tree in isolation.

`git apply` also includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d064702be39d974d0eee403f4fbae92f8f0534a7/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L64-L70):

> ### `--cached`:
>
> Apply the patch to just the index, without touching the working
> tree.
>
> If `--check` is in effect, merely check that it would
> apply cleanly to the index entry.